# ¿Cómo escribir estos bucles anidados en Java?

Tags: java, python, bucle-for

Estoy intentando traducir el siguiente código hecho en Python a Java:

```
numero = int(input())
for i in range(1, numero + 1):
  printer = i
  for j in range(1, i+1):
      print(printer, end=" ")
      printer += 2
  print("")
```

Introduciendo, por ejemplo, el valor de 4, obtendría el siguiente resultado:

```
1 
2 4 
3 5 7 
4 6 8 10
```

El problema es a la hora de declarar las variables fuera de los bucles en Java, ¿alguna ayuda por favor? Mi código en Java es:

```
int print;

for (int=num=1, num<=4; num++) {
  print = num;
  System.out.println(" ");
  for (int j=1; j<=print; j++) {
     System.out.print(print);
     print =+2;
     }
  }
```

Muchas gracias y un saludo!

Comment: ´numero = ParseInt(loquesea)´

Comment: Es casi lo mismo, solo cambia la sintaxis del ciclo for por la correspondiente en java, luego agregas el `;` al final de las líneas que lo necesitan y reemplazar el `print` por `system.out.println`

Comment: ```int print; for int```

Comment: He actualizado el código con lo que tengo en Java, ¿alguna idea? Muchas gracias!

Comment: *El problema es a la hora de declarar las variables fuera de los bucles en Java* -> Tu problema es que no conoces la sintaxis básica de java, porque esto: `int=num=1` no tiene sentido ... y no solo no tiene sentido en java, si no que no tiene sentido en general. Lo que necesitas es *aprender* java. No podemos ayudarte a *aprender*, podemos ayudarte con algún error concreto pero el que debe aprender el lenguaje eres tu. Hiciste un bucle bien (el de la j), por qué el otro lo haces diferente?? Te recomiendo que repases los conceptos básicos de java antes de nada

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo código probado que funciona correctamente

```
                int print;

                for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                    print = i;
                    System.out.println("");

                    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                        System.out.print(print + " ");
                        print = print + 2;
                    }
                }
```

En java `int=num=1,` no tiene sentido además de que en el ciclo for cada condición se separa por punto y coma de esta forma `for(int i = 0; i < *cualquier valor*; i++)` de igual forma en `print =+2;` estas invirtiendo el orden el *+* va delante del = asd.

Y el mayor error es incluir la variable **print** que estas aumentando como condición del ciclo, al hacer esto creas un ciclo infinito ya que nunca la variable **j** que solo aumenta en 1 por ciclo llegará a ser mayor que **print** que aumenta en 2, mucho cuidado con eso y espero que te sea de utilidad.

Aquí tienes una página que explica un poco mas en profundidad el [ciclo for](https://www.example.com/)

Comment: ¡Millones de gracias Ernesto!

Answer (score 0):

Así en un primer vistazo veo algunos errores en tu código. Por un lado, has puesto en el for **int=num=1,** donde debería decir **int num=1;** (sobra un igual y has puesto coma en lugar de punto y coma). Por otra parte, en el segundo bucle has puesto **j<=print** donde debería decir **j<=num**, ya que con la primera expresión el bucle sería infinito puesto que **print** se incrementa constantemente dentro del bucle. Por último, donde has puesto **print =+2** debería poner **print += 2**, esto es, el mas antes del igual (operador de incremento).

En cualquier caso, este código se puede simplificar también de esta manera

```
for (int num=1; num<=4; num++) {
  System.out.println(" ");
  for (int j=0; j<num; j++) {
   System.out.print(num+j*2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

primero en el código de Python estás solicitando el número por consola para esto en java debes importar la libreria util y instanciar un objeto de la clase Scanner

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
```

una vez realizado esto creas una variable de tipo int en la que se almacena el número ingresado por teclado

```
    int numero;
    System.out.println("ingrese el número:");
    numero=sc.nextInt();
```

finalmente con el número realizas el bucle for generando la variable printer:

```
    int printer;

    for (int i = 1; i <=numero; i++) {
       printer=i
       for (int j = 1; i <=i; j++) {
           System.out.println(printer+" ");
       }
        
    }
```